Android Gradle Plugin & Kotlin Compilation Error in Flutter Project on VS Code
Everytime I run my flutter project on vs code using an Android Studio emulator, I encounter this error and I don’t how to fix it. Any help?
    WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 34
    
    This Android Gradle plugin (7.3.0) was tested up to compileSdk = 33
    
    This warning can be suppressed by adding
        android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=34
    to this project's gradle.properties
    
    The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
    use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 34
    
    Task :path_provider_android:processDebugManifest                                                                                                      
    package="io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\path_provider_android-2.2.9\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml.
    Setting the namespace via a source AndroidManifest.xml's package attribute is deprecated.
    Please instead set the namespace (or testNamespace) in the module's build.gradle file, as described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
    This migration can be done automatically using the AGP Upgrade Assistant, please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.
    
    Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
    Compilation with Kotlin compile daemon was not successful
    java.lang.Exception: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.CompileService$CallResult$Error.get(CompileService.kt:60)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.CompileService$CallResult$Error.get(CompileService.kt:59)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.compileWithDaemon(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:220)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.compileWithDaemonOrFallbackImpl(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:152)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.run(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:126)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction.execute(GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers.kt:79)
            at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
            at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
            at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
            at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
            at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
            at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
            at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)        
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)        
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
            at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
            at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
            at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:212)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
            at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:114)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    
    Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy.
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.arguments.ParseCommandLineArgumentsKt.parsePreprocessedCommandLineArguments(parseCommandLineArguments.kt:88) 
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.arguments.ParseCommandLineArgumentsKt.parseCommandLineArguments(parseCommandLineArguments.kt:70)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.arguments.ParseCommandLineArgumentsKt.parseCommandLineArguments$default(parseCommandLineArguments.kt:67)     
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:52)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:43)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(CLITool.kt:179)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit$default(CLITool.kt:177)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMain(CLITool.kt:166)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler$Companion.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt:238)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.reflect.full.KClasses
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
            ... 10 more
    
    Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols
    Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libVkLayer_khronos_validation.so, libflutter.so.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

    Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
    > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
       > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
63 actionable tasks: 51 executed, 12 up-to-date/

I tried deleting gradle and installing it again and it still didn't help, so it's not a gradle problem.
I also tried updating my kotlin version but it still didn't help.
I just created a new project and here's a message I got in the output:
[first_app] flutter pub get --no-example
Resolving dependencies...
Because first_app depends on cwc_flutter any which doesn't exist (could not find package cwc_flutter at https://pub.dev), version solving failed.
exit code 69

Also here's the main.dart file:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Text(title);
  }
}

and here's pubspec.yaml
name: new_project
description: "A new Flutter project."
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
# publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.4.3 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages


Hey dear Neda and welcome to our community. Please provide the code of your main.dart and also pubspec.yaml file, so We can help you out.

@AmirHossein
I just added a new message that appeared while creating a new project, providing also my main.dart and pubspec.yaml

@AmirHossein
but in pubspec.yaml there's nothing named "cwc_flutter", i searched using ctrl+shift+f for anything like that but still couldn't find it.

Please run flutter clean and tell me the result

@AmirHossein
Update: I created a new project and immedietly removed cwc_flutter from pubspec, so now it's fixed, but I still can't run the project using an android studio emulator because the assembleDebug error keeps appearing. I can only run it using web(chrome).

Tell me the debug error

@AmirHossein It’s the first error I provided in my question.
